# Nativescript Core > TabStripItem auto-formatting text (Android)

Tags: android, nativescript

Re-posted here from [here](https://github.com/orgs/NativeScript/discussions/9880)

I'm working with Tabs / TabStrip / TabStripItem and I'm running into a problem (this is only tested on Android).

I'm creating a Label using a FormattedString and Span tags. Each Span tag has its own style (its own fontSize / fontWeight).

When I attach this Label to the TabStripItem 'label' property, it removes the Span's style and resets it all to default.

Here's my code:

```
const createTabLabel = (name, description) =>
{
    const tabTitle = new Label();

    const title = new Span();
    title.text = name + '\n';
    title.fontSize = 24;

    const subTitle = new Span();
    subTitle.text = description;
    subTitle.fontSize = 8;

    const formattedStringLabel = new FormattedString();
    formattedStringLabel.spans.push(title);
    formattedStringLabel.spans.push(subTitle);

    tabTitle.formattedText = formattedStringLabel;

    return tabTitle;
}
```

Tab creation here:

```
export const createTabs = (collection) =>
{
    const tabs = new Tabs();
    const tabStrip = new TabStrip();

    const tabStripItems = [];
    const tabContentItems = [];

    const tabLabel = createTabLabel( "Title", "Sub-Title");
    const tabStripItem = new TabStripItem();
    tabStripItem.label = tabLabel;

    const nestedStack = new StackLayout();
    nestedStack.addChild(tabLabel);

    const contentItem = new TabContentItem();
    contentItem.content = nestedStack;

    tabStripItems.push(tabStripItem);
    tabContentItems.push(contentItem);

    tabStrip.items = tabStripItems;
    tabs.tabStrip = tabStrip;

    tabs.items = tabContentItems;

    return tabs;
}
```

As you can see, the fontSize change gets applied when the Label is displayed on the StackLayout but not inside the TabStripItem
[image]

Oddly enough, changing the TabStripItem object's "textTransform" to "none" removes the uppercasing:

```
tabStripItem.textTransform = "none";
```

I'm just wondering how I can edit the Tab's label css programmatically. I'm using dynamic data. Number of tabs / name and content is all dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

You could add `title.class` and `subTitle.class` to specify a css class name.  If you need greater css specificity you could use `title.style` and `subTitle.style` and include in-line css.

Edit:

See the [tabs styling doc](https://v7.docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/tabs#styling). You may have limited options on the text size.

If you create a an empty, tabbed project you'll see how the tabs can be styled.  In particular, in `_app-common.scss`, there's:

```
// Custom tabstrip item class
.navigation__item {
  &:active,
  &:active Label {
    @include colorize($contrasted-color: complementary background 20% 0%);
  }
}
```

You may be able to use variations of this.  I have code with spans such as what you created, and specifying the style worked there.  Tabs are different, though, as the styling doc indicates.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I'll try this and post back my results

Comment: I tried specifying the class name to title/subTitle but the styling is still not being applied.  This is a problem TabStrip not being compatible with Label elements created with FormattedString.  Because if I pass a Label with just text the CSS applies.  Why not just use Label?  I need to create emphasis on the title over the subTitle.  I'm debating whether I should diplay the subtitle in the content instead of the TabStrip.  Might be my only option.

Comment: Thanks for the update!  I'm aware I can change some TabStrip styles such as the color.  I was looking to change the fontSize or even just fontWeight.  I don't think we can change the fontSize per Span, sadly.